# Immutable JS remove property from all elements in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I have this map:

```
{
    x: {
           a:"fff"
       }
    y: {
           a:"dgfhh"
       }
    ...
}
```

How can I remove 'a' prop from all the elements with immutablejs?

Thanks :)

Comment: map and delete.

Comment: Do you have any example for my case?

Answer (score 2):

If `x` and `y` are also Maps you could do

```js
var newMap = oldMap.map(function(item) {
  return item.delete('a');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

May be other better ways are possible, Check the very basic one of doing this task by `looping` over `object`:

```js
let obj = {

   x: {a : 1, b : 2},
   y: {a : 3, b : 4},
   z: {a : 5, b : 6},
   k: {a : 7, b : 8}

}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
    delete obj[key]['a'];
})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Is there an advantage of using immutable.js?

Comment: @user3712353 i don't have much idea about `immutablejs`,  that why i wrote this is very basic solution :)